# How do I structure data that involves 2 or more related data entities

Tags: typescript, data-structures, architecture

I'm not entirely sure how to formulate this question properly, so I'll give an example which hopefully shows the motivation of this question well.

Consider we have 2 data structures:

```js
interface IPerson {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```

```js
interface ISomething {
   personId: number;
   occuredAt: Datetime;
   description: string;
}
```

where I have an array of `IPerson` already fetched from a database in my application.

Now I want to fetch the `ISomething` resource, but I'm not sure wether to store it as a separate array which I could separately index whenever necessary, or wether to append the `ISomething` resource to the `IPerson` object.

Things I had considered so far:

- Keeping it separate does not introduce tight coupling between the entities
- Bundling them together allows for easier access from the IPerson resource, and potentially better performance when accessing this data often.

What is the best way to structure this data? And why?

Answer (score 0):

Most of it depends on what output you want from the process or how much work is going to be done on it.

If you have few entities (less than 10) that you want to fetch from database then the better way to structure data is to combine them. In this way, you'll have less time complexity and data will be easily accessible to your system but If your system requires more resources then it will be good to keep every entity separate. you'll be able to provide easier modifications and reusability. It will become difficult to control complexity, if you combine them in a single entity.